# How to get expiry date for yum repo signing keys

Tags: centos, yum, gpg

I recently had a package signing key expire preventing some automatic updates from installing so am now setting up monitoring to make sure we are alerted if this happens again.

On Debian systems I can use apt-key to show all the repo keys and their expiry dates (if any) but cannot find how to do the equivalent for yum on CentOS

I can get some key info using:

`rpm -q gpg-pubkey --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\t%{SUMMARY}\n'`

But this does not show expiry dates - any idea how to extract this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Red Hat derived systems, the GPG keys are also stored in ASCII armor in the directory `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg-keys`. You can inspect any of the keys from there.

For example, on CentOS 8:

```
[root@localhost ~]# gpg /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial 
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub   rsa4096 2019-05-03 [SC]
      99DB70FAE1D7CE227FB6488205B555B38483C65D
uid           CentOS (CentOS Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>
```

You can use `-v` to see additional details, and you will need to do so on older versions of gpg. This example is from CentOS 7.

```
[root@localhost ~]# gpg -v /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7 
Version: GnuPG v1.4.5 (GNU/Linux)
pub  4096R/F4A80EB5 2014-06-23 CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>
sig        F4A80EB5 2014-06-23   [selfsig]
gpg: armor header:
```

Neither of these have expiry dates, but a key which has an expiry date or is already expired will show the expiry date.

Here is a key with an expiry date in the future:

```
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub   rsa2048 2020-01-21 [SC] [expires: 2032-01-18]
      D25402AB23709F67CDF72CBFB413ACAD6275F250
uid           EuroLinux 8 GPG RPM sign key <support@euro-linux.com>
sub   rsa2048 2020-01-21 [E] [expires: 2032-01-18]
```

And here is a key that already expired:

```
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub   rsa2048 2016-05-20 [SC] [expired: 2019-05-20]
      36EBEB08D346B0A85B58E140EE788F495250AEF3
uid           The UnitedRPMs Project (Key for UnitedRPMs infrastructure) <unitedrpms@protonmail.com>
sub   rsa2048 2016-05-20 [E] [expired: 2019-05-20]
```

---

An optional package `distribution-gpg-keys` contains GPG keys from a variety of different Linux distributions and repositories. When this package is installed, these keys are available in the directory `/usr/share/distribution-gpg-keys`.

Comment: Perfect.  I then can use gpg --with-colons to get all the info separated into fields for easy parsing the same as I am doing with apt-key, just couldn't find where the keys were stored on CentOS!  Thanks for your help